# Looking for a well-behaved distance/similarity measure of how close a matrix B is to the (pseudo-) inverse of a matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning

I have a two matrices, $A$ and $B$ with dimensions ($m$, $n$) and ($n$, $m$), respectively. I have an iterative machine learning algorithm (similar to a [restricted Boltzmann machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Boltzmann_machine)) that changes the values of $A$ and $B$ over time. I have good reasons to suspect that due to these changes, $B$ becomes similar to the inverse of $A$ (i.e. $A'$) over time / with training (aside: I have some data samples, where each data point is some vector $v$ with length $m$; transforming $v$ using $A$ gives me a new vector $u$ of length $n$ with 
$u = Av$; applying $B$ to $u$ gives me $w = Bu$, which over time becomes similar to the original $v$, i.e., the sum of squared errors between $v$ and $w$ decreases).

*I would like to characterize the degree to which $B$ becomes the inverse of $A$ over time, and I am looking for a well-behaved similarity measure to do so.*

The best that I have come up with so far is based on the identity $I = AA'$: I define a $J = AB$ and compute the ratio $Tr(J) / |J|$, i.e. the sum of values on the diagonal of  $J$ compared to the sum of all values of $J$ (if $B$ is the pseudo-inverse, then there should be no off-diagonal terms). The measure is nice as if $B = A'$ then the measure is 1; however, it is unclear to me what values lower than 1 mean, and if a change in the measure from 0.1 to 0.2 is comparable in some way to a change from 0.4 to 0.5.

I am hence looking for either

a) a more principled similarity measure, or

b) some insight into how $Tr(AB) / |AB|$ behaves as B becomes less and less like the pseudo-inverse of A.

As you can probably tell, I am not a mathematician by training so any comments or suggestions on how to improve the question are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with rectangular matrices, you might get $(AA^+\ne I)$, even using the exact pseudoinverse. Instead you should use the  [Penrose condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) $$AA^+A=A$$ to test how well $B$ approximates $A^+$.

You could use this condition in a ratio test to compare the initial iteration to the $k^{th}$ iteration, e.g.
$$\rho_k = \frac{\|A_kB_kA_k-A_k\|}{\|A_0B_0A_0-A_0\|}$$
Obviously, $\rho_0=1\,$ and if your hunch is correct then $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\rho_k = 0$$

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to base the measure on the Penrose-condition. That does seem the safer thing to do. Unfortunately, your ratio $\rho$ is not a good measure in my case, as the absolute values of $B$ typically increase by quite a bit during learning. If I try to counteract that by normalizing the numerator (and/or the denominator) of $\rho$ with $||B||$, I just get values very close to 1 back.

Comment: @Paul A better-scaled ratio might $$\rho_k = \frac{\|A_kB_kA_k-A_k\|_F}{\|A_k\|_F}$$